# Deriving the Integral Voltage-Current Relationship of a Capacitor

Tags: voltage, capacitor, formula-derivation

I am having trouble understanding the derivation of the capacitor voltage equation in my circuits textbook.

[Here is the process they followed from the textbook](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y2TyP.png)

My confusion is: when the initial voltage across the capacitor is not able to be discerned, that it is "mathematically convenient to set t0 = −∞ and v(−∞) = 0"

Why would t0 be set to −∞ and wouldn't v(−∞) = −∞ not 0?

Comment: Has there been a finite positive current flowing into the capacitor since \$t=-\infty\$?

Comment: It doesn't say. The full explanation they provided is in that image, hence my confusion.

Comment: Those choices don't apply to every problem. They don't even make sense in some cases. Suppose \$i(t)=I\cos\left(\omega t\right)\$. Then the limit of \$v(t)\$ as \$t\to -\infty\$ isn't even well defined.

Comment: So, what are they hoping readers take away from this? Usually, the math helps me understand the concept, but now I'm just confused.

Comment: There are some examples where it will work, like \$i(t)=I u(t)\$. Hopefully the book has some worked examples that will make it more clear. Just don't treat this as a universal rule.

Comment: In their single example, they show graphically that current has been zero up to t=0 and then state that v(t0)=v(−∞)=0. They then state that v(t)=0 when t<=0. They never explain why the v(−∞)=0 is true.

Comment: Mainly because in any real capacitor there is a leakage current. So any initial charge that was there several hours or days or years ago will have leaked away and not affect the circuit in the time range you are actually interested in.

Comment: That makes sense. I'm not sure why they don't just say that. Thank you so much for helping to explain this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the interest of having an actual answer posted after working this out in comments:

This is not a universal rule. It only works for certain types of current waveforms, specifically when

$$\lim_{t_0\to -\infty}\int_{t_0}^{t_1} i(t) {\rm d}t$$ is well defined for some finite \$t_1\$.

It is reasonable to assume the "initial" voltage as \$t\to-\infty\$ is 0 because the leakage current in real capacitors means that any charge that was present a sufficiently long time ago will have leaked away and not affect the behavior circuit in the time range we're actually interested in.